# Flutter ExpansionPanelList.radio - how to preserve expansion on rebuild

Tags: flutter, panel, expand

I can create and display `ExpansionPanelList.radio` just fine. It's `children` property contains a list of `ExpansionPanelRadio` items. All it works as it should - except one thing:

When I navigate to some other tab and then back to tab containing my `ExpansionPanelList.radio`, the `ExpansionPanelRadio` item that was previously expanded is now collapsed.

I would like to be able to keep the last expanded `ExpansionPanelRadio` expanded, but it's `isExpanded` property is read-only. And unlike `ExpansionPanel`, `ExpansionPanelRadio` does't define `isExpanded` in its constructor.

Any idea on how this can be achieved?
Thanks!

Edit: To clarify, here is a code displaying `EpxpansionPalnelList.radio`:

```
class ProductsByApplicationWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final ProductsByApplication productsByApplication;
  final int indexOfExpandedFieldOfApplication;

  const ProductsByApplicationWidget(
      {Key key, @required this.productsByApplication, @required this.indexOfExpandedFieldOfApplication})
      : assert(productsByApplication != null),
        assert(indexOfExpandedFieldOfApplication != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: _buildPanel(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildPanel() {
    return ExpansionPanelList.radio(
      animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      children:
      productsByApplication.productsForApplicationList
          .map<ExpansionPanel>((ProductsForApplication productsForApplication) {
        return ExpansionPanelRadio(
          canTapOnHeader: true,
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return FieldOfApplicationHeaderCellWidget(application: productsForApplication.application,);
          },
          body: Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
              child: Column(
                children:
                productsForApplication.products.map<ProductCellWidget>((Product product) {
                  return ProductCellWidget(product: product);
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          value: productsForApplication.application.id,

        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show minimal code to get a better idea of how you have implemented?

Comment: @OMiShah Code snippet added.

Answer (score 2):

To keep the state, implement `Stack` with `Offstage`. Doing so will keep the state. BTW, you can also use the `key` property.

**An example:**

```
import 'package:bottom_navy_bar/bottom_navy_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Demo extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _DemoState createState() => _DemoState();
}

class _DemoState extends State<Demo> {

  int _currentIndex = 0; // to keep the index of currently selected tab

  Stack _bodyWidgets() {
    return Stack( children: <Widget>[
      Offstage(
          offstage: _currentIndex != 0,
          child: TickerMode(enabled: _currentIndex == 0, child: _screen1Body())),
      Offstage(
        offstage: _currentIndex != 1,
        child: TickerMode(
          enabled: _currentIndex == 1,
          child: Text(("Screen 2"),
        ),
      )),
      Offstage(
        offstage: _currentIndex != 2,
        child: TickerMode(
          enabled: _currentIndex == 2,
          child: Text("Screen 3")),
        ),
    ]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("DEMO"),
        ),
        body: _bodyWidgets(),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavyBar(
            selectedIndex: _currentIndex,
            onItemSelected: (index) => _onTabTapped(index),
            showElevation: true,
            items: [
              BottomNavyBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  title: Text('Screen1')),
              BottomNavyBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.photo),
                  title: Text('Screen2'),
              ),
              BottomNavyBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
                  title: Text('Screen3'),
                 ),
             
            ]));
  }

  void _onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  _screen1Body() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 100,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5), child: Text(i.toString()));
      },
    );
  }
}
```